# Would like to pass a CSS ID to selector in a different page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to pass a variable in JQuery from one web page to another on the click of a link.

For example. I have two web pages (Page1.html and Page2.html) and both contain Jquery scripts

When a user clicks on a link within Page1.html , I would like a variable to be passed to the JQuery script that resides in Page2.html

Thanks so much!

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Answer (score 1):

With HTML5, you can use

```
var myValue = 10;

localStorage.setItem("the value", value);
```

To set a value in the local storage of your domain and use

```
localStorage.getItem("the value");
```

On your second page to retrieve the value.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1:**

You can send the variable without jQuery in Page 1, just by passing the value in the URL.

**Example:**

`<a href="page2.html?variable=value">Link</a>`

**Solution 2:**

The HTML in Page 1

`<a href="page2.html" id="element">Link</a>`

jQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {  
    jQuery('#element').click(function(e)
    {
      e.preventDefault();
      var url=jQuery(this).attr('href');
      var send_data="sample"; /* data you need to send */
      document.location='page2.html?variable'+send_data
    }) 

});
```

**In Page2.html common for both the solutions**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var value = get_variable("variable"); /* The data you send from page1.html will be stored in this variable value */

function get_variable(variable)
{
     var returnvalue = "";
     var url = window.location;
     var breaks = url.split('?'); /* Separating the file name and sent variables */
     var values = breaks[1].split('&'); /* breaking for multiple arguements  */

     for ( var i=0; i<values.length; i++)
     {
          var valsplit = values[i].split('=');

          if ( valsplit[0] == variable )
          {
              returnvalue = valsplit[1]; /* Returning our desired variable  */
          }
     }

     return returnvalue;
}
</script>
```